# Grouping sensor data overtime with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

We have sensors starting and running for a random duration multiple times a day. The data from the sensors are sent to a Kafka topic and is consumed by Spark Structured streaming API and is stored to a Delta Lake. Now we have to identify and store sessions for each sensor in a different Delta Lake table partitioned by device_id and sensor_id.

I tried with Spark Structured Streaming with watermarking but didn't do much good.

```
stream2 = spark.readStream.format('delta')
             .load('<FIRST_DELTA_LAKE_TABLE>')
             .select('device_id', 'json', 'time')
             .withWatermark('timestamp', '10 minutes')
             .groupBy('device_id').agg(F.min('time').alias('min_time'), F.max('time').alias('max_time')))
             .writeStream
             .format("delta")
stream2.start("<SESSIONS_TABLE>")
```

The idea was to have second table identifying the sessions from incoming data and saving the start time and end time for each session and device. The streaming jobs runs and nothing gets written to the Sessions delta table.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually they are in 2 separate streaming jobs. The first streaming job is just writing the raw data to a Delta table and this is the second streaming job which reads the data from that Delta table.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the when you're writing a stream, it uses the `append` mode by default (see the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes)).  And in this mode, when you're using watermarks, the data output only after the watermark is crossed, so there will be at least 10 minutes delay until you start to see the data in the output.

But I think that the primary problem is that you're running the "global" aggregations, without defined window, or something like.  Usually for session detection people use `flatMapGroupWithState`, something like described in the following [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html).

Comment: I am working with pyspark. Is flatMapGroupWithState supported in python?

Comment: ah, didn't notice that's Python... No, it's available only in Java/Scala

Comment: I addressed this in batch mode by using group by and with lag on timestamp. Is there any way to find the time difference between successive messages for device with spark streaming?

Comment: you can also partition by window, and search there... but if sensor may send data at any time, then the window size may not be best approach